# how to set different colors for UIBezeirPath by selecting color options

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am working with UIBezeirPath, and in my drawRect method, I have taken a hardcoded color to setStroke for my path(line) in the below way

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
 [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
 for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
 {
      [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

  }
}
```

this works fine and set red color for the path(line) I draw. Now when I select diffrent color from color options, suppose I select blue color, now when I start to draw the path, the color is blue, **but the previous drawn red line also changes to blue.and that is the whole issue**

below is my code how I am setting different colors

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
if(changecolor)
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        strokeColor = appDelegate.color;
        NSLog(@"%@",strokeColor);

        SEL blackSel = NSSelectorFromString(strokeColor);
        UIColor* tColor = nil;
        if ([UIColor respondsToSelector: blackSel])
            tColor  = [UIColor performSelector:blackSel];
        [tColor setStroke];
        [tColor setFill];       
    }
    else
    {    
        [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
        [[UIColor redColor] setFill];

        for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
        {
            [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

        }
   }
}
```

Whether I am doing this right way, or am I missing something. please help me out

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Hello friends,please help me out

Comment: You should use NSDictionary. Use color and path as key and object respectively and add that to your array. Iterate this array in drawrect by iterating over all keys. You will get all keys and their corresponding objects .

Answer (score 5):

Just maintain current color in one array and bezierpaths in another array. Then do the drawing like following.

```
    int q=0;

for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
{
UIColor *_color = [colorArray objectAtIndex:q];
[_color setStroke];
[_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0]; 
q++;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Veeraraj, thanks for replying, can you look at this link, I am stuck with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502320/eraser-not-working-in-ios-drawing.