# eraser not working in iOS drawing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am working on a drawing project, where I have an eraser option. The code given below is for when I start my app and draw some lines and the proceed to use the eraser. It works fine and I get the eraser effect. Now the second scenario is where I draw some 10 lines and then click on the "undo button" and undo the whole thing, then I redo the whole thing, and now when I click on the "eraser button" and try to erase some part, but instead, it will clear the whole drawing. This is what I am trying to figure out, but i'm not understanding where I am going wrong so friends, please help me out.

Below is my code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{


      case DRAW:
    {
        [m_curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

        CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(m_previousPoint1, m_previousPoint2); 
        CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(m_currentPoint, m_previousPoint1);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 



        [self.layer renderInContext:context];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, m_previousPoint1.x, m_previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
        CGContextStrokePath(context); 
       //            [super drawRect:rect];           
    }
         break;



        case ERASE:
        {
            [m_curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();     
            CGContextClearRect(context, rect);                
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
            [super drawRect:rect];
            break;                

  }      


        case UNDO:
        {
            [m_curImage drawInRect:self.bounds];
             break;

        }

        case REDO:
        {
            [m_curImage drawInRect:self.bounds];  
             break;           
        }


        default:
            break;
    }    
}
```

These are functions that run when I click on undo/redo.

```
-(void)redrawLine
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    NSDictionary *lineInfo = [m_lineArray lastObject];
    m_curImage = (UIImage*)[lineInfo valueForKey:@"IMAGE"];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];   
}


-(void)undoButtonClicked
{
    if([m_lineArray count] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *line = [m_lineArray lastObject];
        [m_bufferArray addObject:line];
        [m_lineArray removeLastObject];
        [self redrawLine];
    }
    m_drawStep = UNDO;

}

-(void)redoButtonClicked
{
    if([m_bufferArray count] > 0)
    {
        NSMutableArray *line = [m_bufferArray lastObject];
        [m_lineArray addObject:line];
        [m_bufferArray removeLastObject];        
        [self redrawLine];
    }
     m_drawStep = REDO;

}
```

Please tell me whether I am doing it right.

Regards,

Ranjit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this issue, the problem  and below is the code which works perfectly

```
case :ERASE
{
 CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(m_previousPoint1, m_previousPoint2); 
            CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(m_currentPoint, m_previousPoint1);

            [m_curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

            [self.layer renderInContext:context];
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
            CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, m_previousPoint1.x, m_previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);


            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
            CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
            CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);  
            CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES); 
            CGContextSetFlatness(context, 0.1f);

            CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
            CGContextStrokePath(context); 
}
```

Regards
Ranjit.

This solved my issue, if anyone has the same issue, please implement this.

Comment: I am also working on the same functionality, But this erase not working for me , Can you please help me .When I am in erase mode its not drawing anything not clearing anything ..Please help me

Comment: Sorry .When I am in erase mode its drawing normally , not clearing anything ..Please help me

Comment: I fixed the problem , need to set the background color of drawing to clear color ..thanks a lot for you solutions

Comment: Hello Ranjit,
I am also working on drawing functionality but i am unable to draw...

Actually i have shape layer which consists path i want to fill colors inside that particular path... but when i try to fill colors it doesn't worked..

I worked till now...
I had added a UIImageview above of that layer and then if i try to fill colors it will work but when i try to merge the same into below cashape layer which having path it won't work. It actually get merged below the bezier path. I want to do above bezier path.

Could you please resolve my issue. It would be great help.

Answer (score 2):

Here what is happening is when you erase the whole rect will get clear na?? so instead of using that erase method draw line in same color that of screen so that it will look like window is clearing and its easy too jus try out this.

For example
if your drawing screen is black then draw line for touchesmoved on screen in black color so that it will look like clearing.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  lastPoint = [touch locationInView:imagevw];
  }

  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:imagevw];
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imagevw.frame.size);

  [self.imagevw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imagevw.frame.size.width,        self.imagevw.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), width);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // black color
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
     imagevw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This is code to draw line in black color on black view... just try out...it may help you..

Comment: ya thats fine, but can you tell me whats the issue with my code?,because it will not work only on undo redo and that too some times.

Comment: I don no exactly whats happening it may be because of you storing all last object while undoing and redoing so after that if you do erase it will clear whole rect wat you stored for previous action i think...don no. sorry

Comment: hey no problem Sandhya, thats fine, anyways, thanks a lot, you spared your time to my question. Do you have any other way to store undo and redo operations?

Comment: This will break if you are drawing on an UIImageview containing an UIImage.